# Regex to match Java String

Tags: java, regex, scala

In Scala's parser combinators ([JavaTokensParser](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/JavaTokenParsers.scala#L1) in particular) there is a definition [stringLiteral](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/JavaTokenParsers.scala#L50) that matches a Java-like string.

```
def stringLiteral: Parser[String] =
              ("\""+"""([^"\p{Cntrl}\\]|\\[\\'"bfnrt]|\\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})*"""+"\"").r
```

Unfortunately, this regex [does not work for long strings](https://github.com/scala/scala/issues/3017).  Does anyone know of a re-usable implementation that does, or a modification to the regex that is more space efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem!!

Just played around with this, and came up with the following:

```
val r = ("\"" + "(?:[^\"\\p{Cntrl}\\\\]*|(?:\\\\(?:[\\\\'\"bfnrt]|u[a-fA-F0-9]{4}))*)*" + "\"").r
```

**Note:** the above regex was fixed from the first version… both the leading '\' and the trailing characters need to be repeated, not just the trailing characters as I originally had it!

**Edit:** Found a more efficient regular expression. Using the following, it can parse a string of up to 950 `\\ns` pairs, as opposed to the original which could only parse 556, at least in my default configuration.

```
val r = ("\"" + "(?:[^\"\\p{Cntrl}\\\\]*|\\\\[\\\\'\"bfnrt]|\\\\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})*" + "\"").r
```

**Edit 2:** Based on the comment from @schmmd, I have an even better regular expression. This one can parse the 2500 `\ns` torture case. The secret is to use the greedy possessive modifier, this basically turns off the need to backtrack, and hence also turns off the recursion.

```
val r = (""""([^"\p{Cntrl}\\]*+(?:\\[\\'"bfnrt])*+(?:\\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})*+)*+"""").r
```

The essence of the solution is to try and chew as much as you can each time that you match something.

```
scala> val r = (""""([^"\p{Cntrl}\\]*+(?:\\[\\'"bfnrt])*+(?:\\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})*+)*+"""").r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = "([^"\p{Cntrl}\\]*+(?:\\[\\'"bfnrt])*+(?:\\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})*+)*+"

scala> r.pattern.matcher("\"" + "\\ns" * 2500 + "\"").lookingAt
res4: Boolean = true

scala> r.pattern.matcher("\"" + "s" * 2500 + "\"").lookingAt
res5: Boolean = true
```

**Update:** A [pull request](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators/pull/4) was submitted to the scala folks. And it was accepted.

Comment: Your regex is fine, but it makes sense to me to remove all the disjunctions.  It still overflows on your `"\\ns" * 2500` though. `("\"" + """([^"\p{Cntrl}\\]*(?:\\[\\'"bfnrt])*(?:\\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})*)*""" + "\"").r`.

Comment: Switching all my Kleene stars to possessive Kleene stars provides better performance. ("\"" + """([^"\p{Cntrl}\\]*+(?:\\[\\'"bfnrt])*+(?:\\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})*+)*+""" + "\"").r

Comment: @schmmd You are right! The possessive operator is indeed the answer. You could even use that in the original answer, and it solves the issue as well.

Comment: I'll accept your answer for now.  I would love to hear of a library that parsers for this pattern in it, along with methods to convert the parsed Java string into a `String` instance.

Comment: I do hope this gets submitted to the Scala library.